# Create new variables with foreach loop

Tags: php, json, loops, variables, foreach

I got this

```
$data   = json_decode($json, true)["value1"];
```

after this I sort the response to name value:

```
foreach($data as $test) {
echo $test['name'];
}
```

this shows me all names I need, this worked perfectly.

```
Output: name1 name2 name3
```

Question: 
What have I to do, to get the foreach output in new single variables, so I can use them through the rest of the script ?

```
Expl.: $name_1 = name1;
```

it maybe that I completely wrong.

so much thanks from a newbie who writes his 1st project.

Comment: Why do you need individual variables to be able to use them throughout the rest of the script? Why can't you use the array? Numbered variables bad, arrays good!

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. At this point I think its the easiest way for me, or I don't know a better way :)

I want to use the "new variables" as names in a HTML File, only for echo, to label serval tables through a html file.

Expl.:

new Variable from foreach loop maybe $name_1 this I want use to label a header of a table

Comment: A better way to do this would be to use them in the array instead of reassigning them. You can interact with them directly. Ex. `$data[0]` would echo name1

Comment: Hi, thanks yes this I know and runs in a other script in the project. Background I want to have a dynamic script which read out the names from the JSON, this value I need to sort some data and use them to create new requests.

Answer (score 5):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
$i = 1;
foreach($data as $test) {
    ${'name_'.$i++} = $test['name'];
}
```

Although using an array for this is almost always the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't comfortable with the json array, you can push the values to a new array:

```
$names = array();
foreach($data as $value)
{array_push($names,$value['name']);}
```

But creating variables dynamically and use them like arrays usually isn't a good way to go. Literally, that's what arrays are used for.

Answer (score 0):

big thanks to you all, I think i solved with your inspiration.

after thinking in view of your answer, I tried a other step and now i got all the data i need in an array which i can access every the single data.

```
$data = json_decode($json, true)["value1"];

$value_names = array();

foreach($data as $value)
{
    $value_names[]=$value{'name'};
}
```

so now all data in the array:

```
array(8) { [0]=> string(6) "name" [1]=> string(6) "name" [2]=> string(10) "name" [3]=> string(12) "name" [4]=> string(12) "name" [5]=> string(9) "name" [6]=> string(13) "name" [7]=> string(4) "name" }
```

if I resolve this I got more question :) but I study myself before I ask so I practice my skills. Big thanks to the community !!!